# Carleson embedding theorem

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Carleson embedding theorem gives a criterium by which to decide when for a measure $\mu$ the operator that takes a function on the real line to its harmonic extension (by convolution with Poisson kernel) on the upper half-plane is bounded from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2_+,\mu)$.

Why is this theorem so significant? Why is this question interesting? Why is it called "embedding" theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this theorem so significant?

Because it's used to prove other theorems. See *Operators, Functions, and Systems: An Easy Reading (Volume 1)* by Nikolski, page 130.

> Why is this question interesting?

This is subjective. If you do not find a result interesting, then it's not interesting to you.

> Why is it called "embedding" theorem?

Because a bounded injective operator between spaces of functions is often called an embedding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I can not draw much satisfaction from the second point. It was supposed to be a question for some motivation of this problem.

Comment: @Anonymous999 Then I'm a wrong person to ask. I don't believe in motivation.